# Android sherlock actionbar tabs alignment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm using Android sherlock fragment tabs for creating a layout for swiping the tabs.

Now what I want to do is put the tabs below a relative layout , but the tabs headers are appearing at the top while it's content is appearing where it should be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use standalone tabs widget like https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
or move existing tabs using technique (really hack) described at http://kriomant.blogspot.ru/2013/08/navigation-drawer-tabs-overlap.html

But in case of hack current tab indicator will still be drawn at the bottom. I didn't investigate whether it is possible to move it.